# How to add dynamically created buttons to a dynamically created table?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

A question has been really bugging me lately. I hope you would help me.

I want to create a table after a user clicks a button. On each row in the first cell I want to add a button. Unfortunately, the table buttons fail to fire an event. Could you tell me how to do it or where my mistake is? I have used [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/aspnet/dynamiccontrolsByLeon.aspx) to create the following example code.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolderForTable" runat="server">

</asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:Button ID="btnCreateTbl" runat="server" Text="Create Table"/>
<asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" />
```

Code:

```
private struct ControlInfo
{
    public string ID;
    public string Type;
    public int Border;
    public HtmlTableRow[] TblRows;
    public HtmlTableCell[] TblCells;
    public int Width;
    public int Height;
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnCreateTbl.Click+=new EventHandler(BtnClick);
    if (this.IsPostBack) this.RecreatePersistedControls();
}//end Page_Load


//Call CreateControl for each persisted control
private void RecreatePersistedControls()
{
    ArrayList al = (ArrayList)this.Session["DynamicControls"];
    if (al != null)
        foreach (ControlInfo ci in al)
            this.CreateControl(ci);
}//end RecreatePersisterdControls method

//Create control specified by ControlInfo structure
private Control CreateControl(ControlInfo ci)
{
    Control ctl = null;

    switch (ci.Type)
    {
        case "Button":
            ctl = new Button();
            ctl.ID = ci.ID;
            ((Button)ctl).Text = "Edit";
            ((Button)ctl).Click+=new EventHandler(this.DoNothing);
            if (this.placeHolderForTable.FindControl("tblResult") != null)
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < ci.Height; r++)
                {
                    if (this.placeHolderForTable.FindControl("tblResult").FindControl("tr" + (r + 1)) != null && (r+1).ToString()==ci.ID[7].ToString())
                        if (this.placeHolderForTable.FindControl("tblResult").FindControl("tr" + (r + 1)).FindControl("td" + (r + 1) + "1") != null)
                            if(this.placeHolderForTable.FindControl("tblResult").FindControl("tr" + (r + 1)).FindControl("td" + (r + 1) + "1").FindControl(ctl.ID)==null)
                                this.placeHolderForTable.FindControl("tblResult").FindControl("tr" + (r + 1)).FindControl("td" + (r + 1) + "1").Controls.Add(ctl);
                }
            }
            break;
        case "HtmlTable":
            ctl = new HtmlTable();
            ctl.ID = ci.ID;
            ((HtmlTable)ctl).Border = ci.Border;

            for (int r = 0; r < ci.Height; r++)
            {
                HtmlTableRow row = ci.TblRows[r];
                row.ID = "tr" + (r + 1);
                for (int c = r * ci.Width; c < r * ci.Width+2; c++)
                {
                    ci.TblCells[c].ID="td"+(r+1)+(c%2+1);
                    row.Cells.Add(ci.TblCells[c]);

                }
                ((HtmlTable)ctl).Rows.Add(row);
            }
            if(this.placeHolderForTable.FindControl(ctl.ID)==null)
                this.placeHolderForTable.Controls.Add(ctl);
            break;
        default:
            return null;
    }
    return ctl;
}//end CreateControl method

//Create ControlInfo structure and persist it to Session
private ControlInfo PersistControl(string id, string type, int border, HtmlTableRow[] tblRows, HtmlTableCell[] tblCells, int width,
    int height)
{
    ControlInfo ci = new ControlInfo();
    ci.ID = id;
    ci.Type = type;
    ci.Border = border;
    ci.TblRows = tblRows;
    ci.TblCells = tblCells;
    ci.Width = width;
    ci.Height = height;

    ArrayList al = (ArrayList)this.Session["DynamicControls"];
    if (al == null) al = new ArrayList();
    al.Add(ci);
    this.Session["DynamicControls"] = al;
    return ci;
}//end PersistControl method

private void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int cellIx=0,rowIx=0;            
    HtmlTableRow tr1 = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell td11 = new HtmlTableCell();
    tr1.Cells.Add(td11);
    HtmlTableCell td12 = new HtmlTableCell();
    td12.InnerText = "td12";
    tr1.Cells.Add(td12);
    HtmlTableRow tr2 = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell td21 = new HtmlTableCell();
    tr2.Cells.Add(td21);
    HtmlTableCell td22 = new HtmlTableCell();
    tr2.Cells.Add(td22);
    td22.InnerText = "td22";
    HtmlTableRow []arrRows=new HtmlTableRow[2];
    arrRows[rowIx++]=tr1;
    arrRows[rowIx++]=tr2;
    HtmlTableCell []arrCells=new HtmlTableCell[4];
    arrCells[cellIx++]=td11;
    arrCells[cellIx++]=td12;
    arrCells[cellIx++]=td21;
    arrCells[cellIx++]=td22;
    ControlInfo ci = PersistControl("tblResult", "HtmlTable", 3, arrRows, arrCells, 2, 2);
    HtmlTable tblResult = (HtmlTable)CreateControl(ci);

    ci = PersistControl("btnEdit1", "Button", 0, arrRows, arrCells, 2, 2);
    Button btnEdit1 = (Button)CreateControl(ci);

    ci = PersistControl("btnEdit2", "Button", 0, arrRows, arrCells, 2, 2);
    Button btnEdit2 = (Button)CreateControl(ci);
}

public void DoNothing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblResult.Text = (sender as HtmlButton).ID + " done";
}
```

Comment: I know this isn't a particularly constructive comment, but I'm going to use this post as an example of why Microsoft were right to introduce ASP.NET MVC (and why WebForms should never have existed)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic Controls are whole other beast and I try to stay away from them as much as possible. That being said, there are cases where they may be necessary.

The thing about event handlers and dynamic controls, you have to be sure to wire up and add the control to the page control tree in the OnInit or Page_Load functions otherwise they can behave strangely http://support.microsoft.com/?id=317794

I've made some edits to your code that wires up the event handlers at Page_Load. See below and let me know if you have any questions:

```
    // Added a ViewState persisted prop
    bool WireUpControls
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewState["wireUpControls"] != null ? Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["wireUpControls"]) : false;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["wireUpControls"] = value;
        }
    }

    void CreateControlTable()
    {
        int cellIx = 0, rowIx = 0;
        HtmlTableRow tr1 = new HtmlTableRow();
        HtmlTableCell td11 = new HtmlTableCell();
        tr1.Cells.Add(td11);
        HtmlTableCell td12 = new HtmlTableCell();
        td12.InnerText = "td12";
        tr1.Cells.Add(td12);
        HtmlTableRow tr2 = new HtmlTableRow();
        HtmlTableCell td21 = new HtmlTableCell();
        tr2.Cells.Add(td21);
        HtmlTableCell td22 = new HtmlTableCell();
        tr2.Cells.Add(td22);
        td22.InnerText = "td22";
        HtmlTableRow[] arrRows = new HtmlTableRow[2];
        arrRows[rowIx++] = tr1;
        arrRows[rowIx++] = tr2;
        HtmlTableCell[] arrCells = new HtmlTableCell[4];
        arrCells[cellIx++] = td11;
        arrCells[cellIx++] = td12;
        arrCells[cellIx++] = td21;
        arrCells[cellIx++] = td22;
        ControlInfo ci = PersistControl("tblResult", "HtmlTable", 3, arrRows, arrCells, 2, 2);
        HtmlTable tblResult = (HtmlTable)CreateControl(ci);

        ci = PersistControl("btnEdit1", "Button", 0, arrRows, arrCells, 2, 2);
        Button btnEdit1 = (Button)CreateControl(ci);

        ci = PersistControl("btnEdit2", "Button", 0, arrRows, arrCells, 2, 2);
        Button btnEdit2 = (Button)CreateControl(ci);
    }

    // Call CreateControlTable() if we need to create the controls and wire up events
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnCreateTbl.Click += new EventHandler(BtnClick);
        if (WireUpControls) CreateControlTable();
        //if (this.IsPostBack) this.RecreatePersistedControls();

    }

    protected void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       WireUpControls = true;
       CreateControlTable();
    }

    public void DoNothing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblResult.Text = (sender as Button).ID + " done";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, the buttons inside the table still don't fire the event "DoNothing".

Comment: Aha. ViewState["wireUpControls"] must be set to true in BtnClick event(on initial creation of the table).

Comment: Yeah, apologies, I forgot to add the updated code for the BtnClick event...  `WireUpControls = true; CreateControlTable();`

Comment: I've debugged this and it fires... sorry for the missing code initially glad you were able to figure out

Comment: Have you noticed that whichever button you click in the end the text of lblResult is always "editBtn1 done"?