# OnClick function on dynamic LinkButton?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm creating dynamic LinkButton where I assign to it dynamically an ID now I would be able to write an `onClick` function where I get that ID but after trying to make something like that I had no result:

```
  table.Append("<td><asp:LinkButton runat=""server"" class=""edit btn btn-sm btn-default"" ID=" & reader.GetString("id") & " OnClient=""Delete_User""><i class=""fa fa-trash-o"" aria-hidden=""true""></asp:LinkButton></i></a>")
```

While here is VB.NET code

```
Sub Delete_User(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim clickedBtn As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)

    MsgBox(clickedBtn.ID)

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot create a LinkButton as a string. It does not work that way. You need to add REAL control to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LinkButton` is a server control and you cannot render it with same way as you render plain HTML tags from code-behind, it will not work as expected. You need to provide `HtmlTableCell` instance and bind `LinkButton` control from there, assumed `table` is defined as `HtmlTable`:

```
' this is just a sample event
Protected Sub SomeEventHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim table As HtmlTable = New HtmlTable()
    Dim row As HtmlTableRow = New HtmlTableRow()

    ' set the data reader from database here

    Dim cell As HtmlTableCell = New HtmlTableCell()

    Dim linkbtn As LinkButton = New LinkButton()
    linkbtn.ID = reader.GetString("id")                ' setting control ID
    linkbtn.Text = "Delete User"                       ' setting link text
    linkbtn.CssClass = "edit btn btn-sm btn-default"
    AddHandler lnkbutton.Click, AddressOf Delete_User  ' assign event handler

    ' add the control to table cell ('td' element)
    cell.Controls.Add(linkbtn)
    row.Cells.Add(cell)
    table.Rows.Add(row)

    ' other stuff
End Sub
```

Note that you should provide server-side click event with `Click` property which associated with `OnClick` event, not `OnClient` nor `OnClientClick`.

**Additional note:**

`MsgBox` cannot be used in ASP.NET because it belongs to WinForms, you need to provide JS `alert()` function to show message box with `RegisterStartupScript` or `RegisterClientScriptBlock`:

```
Sub Delete_User(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim clickedBtn As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)

    Dim message As String = "alert('" & clickedBtn.ID & "');"

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "MsgBox", message, True)
End Sub
```

Related issues:

[How to add linkbutton control to table cell dynamically](https://forums.asp.net/t/1313957.aspx?How%20to%20add%20linkbutton%20control%20to%20table%20cell%20dynamically%20)

[Creating a link button programmatically](https://forums.asp.net/t/1705344.aspx?Creating%20a%20Link%20Button%20Programmatically)

[How to add dynamically created buttons to a dynamically created table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891805/how-to-add-dynamically-created-buttons-to-a-dynamically-created-table)

Comment: Actually i've solved it by calling throw javascript a QueryString with the ID of the row but this solution working as well and i think it's more secure than what i was doing, thanks